# Android append text file

Tags: android, file, text, append

I am tring to record the wake time and  sleep time from a dialog picker to a text file like this, but the call to the method commitToFile2 doesn't append the text file "savedData.txt."

I know this code is very very dirty.  I'm new to Java so any other suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
package com.buttinyourface;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class SettingsActivity extends Activity {

    public int wakeHour;
    public int wakeMinute;
    public int sleepHour;
    public int sleepMinute;
    public String sleepHourText = "No Data";
    public String sleepMinuteText = "No Data";
    public String outputTime = "No Data";
    public String wakeHourText = "No Data";
    private ListView lv;
    Dialog newDialogBox;
    Context appContext;
    protected Context context;
    static final private int WAKE_TIME = 0;
    static final private int SLEEP_TIME = 1;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.settings);
        final String[] settingsList = getResources().getStringArray(
                R.array.settingsStringArray);
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        TextView wakeHourTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                int settingsPosition = position;
                if (settingsPosition == 0) {
                    showDialog(WAKE_TIME);
                    wakeHourText = Integer.toString(wakeHour);
                }
                if (settingsPosition == 1) {
                    showDialog(SLEEP_TIME);
                }
            }
        });
        lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, settingsList));
        wakeHourTextView.setText(outputTime);
    }

    public void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) {
        switch (id) {
        case WAKE_TIME:
            break;
        case SLEEP_TIME:
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case WAKE_TIME:
            return new TimePickerDialog(this, WakeTimeSetListener, wakeHour,
                    wakeMinute, false);
        case SLEEP_TIME:
            return new TimePickerDialog(this, SleepTimeSetListener, sleepHour,
                    sleepMinute, false);
        }
        return null;
    }

    private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener WakeTimeSetListener =
                          new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            wakeHour = hourOfDay;
            wakeMinute = minute;
            String wakeHourText = Integer.toString(hourOfDay);
            String wakeMinuteText = Integer.toString(minute);
            String preftime = hourOfDay + ":" + minute;
            SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
            SimpleDateFormat dfOut = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mma");
            Date date = null;
            try {
                date = df.parse(preftime);
            } catch (ParseException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            String outputWakeTime = dfOut.format(date);
            try {
                commitToFile(wakeHourText, wakeMinuteText, outputWakeTime);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    private TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener SleepTimeSetListener =
                          new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            sleepHour = hourOfDay;
            sleepMinute = minute;
            String sleepHourText = Integer.toString(hourOfDay);
            String sleepMinuteText = Integer.toString(minute);
            String preftime = hourOfDay + ":" + minute;
            SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
            SimpleDateFormat dfOut = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mma");
            Date date = null;
            try {
                date = df.parse(preftime);
            } catch (ParseException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            String sleepOutputTime = dfOut.format(date);
            try {
                commitToFile2(sleepHourText, sleepMinuteText, sleepOutputTime);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    private void commitToFile(String wakeHourText, String wakeMinuteText,
            String outputWakeTime) throws IOException {
        final String entryString = new String("wakeHour=" + wakeHourText
                + ";wakeMinute=" + wakeMinuteText + ";wakeTime="
                + outputWakeTime + ";");
        FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput("savedData.txt",
                MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
        osw.write(entryString);
        osw.flush();
        osw.close();
    }

    private void commitToFile2(String sleepHourText, String sleepMinuteText,
            String sleepOutputTime) throws IOException {
        final String entryString = new String("sleepHour=" + sleepHourText
                + ";sleepMinute=" + sleepMinuteText + ";sleepTime="
                + sleepOutputTime + ";");
        FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput("savedData.txt",
                MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
        osw.write(entryString);
        osw.flush();
        osw.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: " I'm new to Java so any other suggestions would be greatly appreciated." : USE YOUR IDE'S FORMATTER, for gosh shake. And do not name local variables with initial caps (like SleepTimeSetListener, notice how it is colored like a type above). This makes people not new to java unable to read your code. DO NOT POST redundant info when asking questions (like `// TODO Auto-generated catch block`)

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D - Reading this almost 8 years later.....oh my god I sucked!  Thanks for guiding me in the right direction!

Comment: Hey - welcome :)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I figured it out....I had to change the line

```
FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput("savedData.txt", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
```

to

```
FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput("savedData.txt",  MODE_APPEND);
```

After that I was able to append the text file without overwriting the data that was already inside the text file.  Thanks for your assistance guys.  I guess going to the 4th page on google IS useful sometimes.

Comment: This does not retain `MODE_WORLD_READABLE`, the solution that retains world readability is specified by @Sparkz below

Comment: Where on the device is savedData.txt?

Comment: @kurdtpage I asked this question 8 years ago so my memory is very foggy.  I believe I was writing to a file in the app's default sandbox directory.

Answer (score 17):

that's so you retain your `MODE_WORLD_READABLE`

```
openFileOutput("savedData.txt", MODE_APPEND | MODE_WORLD_READABLE );
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `commitToFile2()` method, after `fw.append(entryString);` try adding `fw.flush();`

`FileWriter` is a subclass of `OutputStreamWriter` and the `write()` methods of that class will not necessarily 'flush' data automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the input Squonk, but I get the same results.  The data in commmitToFile2 is never entered into the text file "savedData.txt".  Originally the guts inside the method commitToFile2 were the same as the guts as the inside commitToFile method, just outputting different arguments to the string "entryString," but that would overwrite the entire file.  I need to append the textfile with the data taken from the subsequent listViews....any ideas?

Comment: ....even changing the fw.append(entryString) to fw.write(entryString) has no effect on the text file.....what the hell?