# Deleting all the contents from a text file Android

Tags: android, string, file

Here is the code for writing a string to a text file.

```
try {
    OutputStreamWriter out=new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("counts.txt", MODE_APPEND));
     try {
         s = main_text.getText().toString();
         out.write(s);
     }
     catch (java.io.IOException e) {
     }
```

Now how to delete all the contents of a text file without deleting the file itself.

Actually when ever adding the next string to a file it appends next to the previous string. What is required is to over write the previous string.

Comment: Also what is APPEND_MODE.

Comment: MODE_APPEND*: File creation mode: for use with openFileOutput, if the file already exists then write data to the end of the existing file instead of erasing it.

Comment: `MODE_APPEND`: rtfm. rarely appropriate, but here I think it is.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use another mode - when you use MODE_APPEND it will append ;-)
I think you should be fine with just changing MODE_APPEND -> 0

Answer (score 0):

**open file and try to write blank string into file.**

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(file);
writer.print("");
writer.close();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23320070/appending-a-string-to-an-existing-file-using-outputstreamwriter

Comment: for other details please check link

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6994518/how-to-delete-the-content-of-text-file-without-deleting-itself