# Appending data to a text file in Android

Tags: android, append, text-files

I am trying to add data to a text file in android using the code below but it only overwrites the data with one line of data.

```
private void copyImageToMemory(File outFile , Float number) {
    try {

        BufferedOutputStream fos = new BufferedOutputStream(
                new FileOutputStream(outFile));


        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(fos)));

        pw.append("result"+number);
        pw.close();
        maxSpeed=0;

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e(TAGFile, "FileNotFoundException");
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android append text file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4542318/android-append-text-file)

Comment: That is for other type of file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `FileOutputStream` constructor allows to specify whether it should append to an already existing file or not:

```
new FileOutputStream(file, true);
```

will create a stream that appends to the given file.